# Node.js - Multiple index.js files being executed

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a node app - in the app directory, I have a worker and an API:

```
.
+-- .gitignore
+-- node_modules
+-- eslintrc.js
+-- src
|   +-- api/index_api.ts
|   +-- worker/index_worker.ts
```

In my `package.json` I have a script for working with my API:

`"dev-api": "nodemon src/api/* ts-node src/api/index_api.ts"`

However what I'm noticing is that both `index_api.ts` and `index_worker.ts` gets called/starts.

Why is this? I assumed by specifying `src/api/index_api.ts` it would only run that index_api.ts?

Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks.